# What is the difference between $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ and $|\mathbf f_k|^2$ what is the relation between $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ and $\mathbf F_k$?

Tags: matrices

What is the difference between $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ and  $|\mathbf f_k|^2$ ?

$\mathbf f_k$ is a $4$ by $1$ matrix,so  $\mathbf F_k$ is a $4$ by $4$ square matrix in fact.

I know $|\mathbf f_k|^2=\mathbf f_k\mathbf f_k^{H}=\mathbf F_k$ ,so i know the relation between $\mathbf F_k$ and $|\mathbf f_k|^2$

But what is the $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ ? the length of $\mathbf F_k$ ?

Comment: Depends on the definitions... ||x|| and |x| are usually interchangeable notations for the modulus of a vector/matrix.

Comment: so can i understand like this  $|\mathbf f_k|^2=\mathbf F_k$,and like you said,it seems ||x|| and |x| can be the same,if we don't care the matrix or vector.so $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ can be equal to $\mathbf F_k$

Comment: Presumably $|v|$ and $\|v\|$ are both numbers, so $|v|^2$ and $\|v\|^2$ are also numbers, and can't be $4\times4$ matrices.

Comment: So the real question is, where did you come across the notations $|f_k|$, $\|f_k\|$, and $F_k$? What was the context? How were they defined?

Comment: @GerryMyerson in the page 5 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08898.pdf ,you can see the OP2 has $||\mathbf f_k||^2$ and $ |\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf f_k|^2.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson By the way , $ |\mathbf f|^2$  should be a $4$ by $4$ matrix.because it is equal to $4$ by $1$  matrix times $1$ by $4$ matrix because $\mathbf f$ is a vector,not a scalar

Comment: It clearly says on page 2 (at the end of section 1B) that $\|v\|$ is the Euclidean norm of the complex vector $v$ (so it's a number), and that $|z|$ is the absolute value of the complex number $z$ (so it's also a number). The notation $|f|$ is never used in thie paper when $f$ is a vector, neither is $|f|^2$. $f$ is a column vector, so $ff^H$ is a $4\times4$ matrix, but $f^Hf$ is a complex scalar, and $\|f\|^2=f^Hf$. In short: the difference between $\|f\|^2$ and $|f|^2$ is that the second one doesn't exist (continued)

Comment: and the relation between $\|f\|^2$ and $F$ is that the former is the square of the modulus of the trace of the latter.

Comment: Do you understand now, shineele?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes! i understand it,thanks for ur explaination